# How to break infinite parent - children loop in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, infinite-loop, bidirectional-relation

I have an app with Pages, and each of them might have child Pages:

**`Page.java`**

```
public class Page{
  ...
  @Nullable
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Page parentPage;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentPage")
  private List<Page> childPages;
  ...
}
```

I want to display a link **`<< Back to parent page`** on each page, and to have links to all its children:

**`view-page.html`**

```
<div ng-if="currentPage.parentPage">
  <a href="#/view-page?pageId={{currentPage.parentPage.id}}">Back to {{currentPage.parentPage.title}}</a>
</div>
...
<div ng-repeat="row in currentPage.childPages">
  <a href="#!/view-page?pageId={{row.id}}">{{row.title}}</a>
</div>
```

This causes an infinite loop parent - child - parent - ...

I tried with @JsonIgnore, but then I lose the info I need (whether it's a parent or a child). I also tried to annotate the parent with `@JsonManagedReference` and the list of child pages with `@JsonBackReference`. Then I could see the parent, but not the children. My next step will be to try and write a custom serializer.

So my question is - does anyone have an idea how can I get a `parentPage` property and still being able to see children without getting into an infinite loop child - parent - child - parent...?

Comment: This means parentPage is not available in ``$scope.currentPage``.
Have you checked that you are getting parentPage data in your response?

Comment: @DevangNaghera It is not in the response, I suppose that's because of JsonIgnore annotation. And if I remove the annotation, I'm entering an infinite loop, because a page has children, which have parents, which have children, which have parents..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. In one of the relations I could use `@JsonIgnore`. In other case I needed to use a custom serializer where I will not load children.